# Android Toolbar: Enable default Up button

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using a Toolbar in place of the action bar, and I'd like to continue to use the default Up icon for my toolbar. I believe it's the ic_menu_back drawable. This resource seems to be private, however, as I can't access it through android.R.drawable.ic_menu_back.

Do I have to extract this image and put it into my drawables folder manually, or is there a way I can just force the Toolbar to use the default Up button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` to handle back clicks on the arrow:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your activity like this :

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
```

You need to import drawable to folders.

Second way is to through styles.xml just add these items :

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back</item>
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```